# Find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $n>N$ makes $\left | a_n-L \right |<\varepsilon$

Tags: limits

For  $a_n = \frac{(-1){^n}(n+4)}{3n{^2}-7}$ and $\varepsilon = 0.001$

I know that $L = 0$, but how do I do the math to find $N$? thanks

Comment: Hint: when applying the absolute value, the $(-1)^n$ disappears, so can you rewrite what the condition $|a_n - 0| < 0.001$ becomes?

Comment: @Basj $|\frac{(n+4)}{3n{^2}-7} - 0| < 0.001$ ?

Comment: @Basj I got many of these to practice, I'd like to get a full insight on this one so I could work on the rest.

Comment: When $n \geq 2$, then the fraction you wrote is positive, and your condition is equivalent to $n+4 < 0.001 (3n^2-7)$. Write this as $ax^2+bx+c > 0$ and you can find the roots, etc.

Comment: @Basj I did find the roots, I get $n=337.287$ and $n=-3.95$

So obviously the negative root isnt valid, but since $n\in\mathbb{N}$ do I put N as 337? or 338?

Comment: 338, because for 337 it's still negative. Try to write a full answer here (as an answer of your own post) so that people can comment/edit if there are mistakes.

Comment: PS: Just replace n by 337 and 338 in `(n+4)/(3*n^2-7)` and you'll see which one is good ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not demanding least such $N $ then you can use estimate $ \frac{n+4}{3 n^{2} -7} \leq   \frac{n+4}{3 n^{2} -48 }  = \frac{1}{3n -4} $  (you can assume n is sufficiently large) now apply $\epsilon $ on last expression to get required $N$.